# The yarn command has no output

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, yarnpkg

My `yarn` command returns immediately, displaying nothing to stdout. Even basic commands like `yarn -v` display nothing. I am on mac osx and recently ran the migration tool from an x86_64 to M2 macbook pro.

- yarn is installed, confirmed with `which yarn`
- yarn exits with error code 1, confirmed with `yarn; echo $?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by going to `$TMPDIR` and removing any directories with ‘v8’ in the name:

```
cd $TMPDIR
ls | grep v8 | xargs rm -rf
```

yarn will read from cache directories in `$TMPDIR`. Directories will be named something like `v8-compile-cache-501`. The cache directories were likely made for x86_64, and when the migration tool ran, yarn still reads from the cache directory but doesn’t know its for the wrong ISA (since new laptop uses arm64). Hope this helps others running into the same problem!

Comment: I'm on Windows and didn't run any migration tool, but this fixed the issue also for me